# How to re-use an element's ID from jQuery 'on' event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display specific HTML based on a particular event.  In this case, it is a button click, which then displays text and one or more button selections.  When a selection is made, the HTML text and buttons presented are determined by an embedded switch statement in the click function.  This process is repeated using the same switch block and "on" event.

The problem I am running into is that within the jQuery function, clicking the newly presented button (e.g. - the button from case 0) doesn't trigger the function, and switch doesn't trigger.  If I do an append, I can click the first button (outside of the function) and it will continuously trigger the function (case 0 again), but from within the switch statement, it doesn't trigger the "on" event.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var stepNum = 0;
$('#content').html('<h1>Start</h1><button id="sendButton">Go to case 0</button>');
$('#sendButton').on('click', function () {
switch(stepNum) {
    case 0:
        $('#content').html('<h1>Switch case 0</h1><button id="sendButton">To case 2</button>');
                stepNum = 2; //Next click would go to case 2
        $('#sendButton').off('click');
        refresh()
        break;
    case 1:
        $('#content').html('<h1>Switch case 1</h1><button id="sendButton">To case 0</button>');
                stepNum = 0; //Next click would go to case 0
        break;
    case 2:
        $('#content').html('<h1>Switch case 2</h1><button id="sendButton">To case 1</button>');
                stepNum = 1; //click would go to case 1
        break;            
    default:
        $('#content').append('<h1>Default!</h1>');
                stepNum = 4;
        }
return false;
});
```

[Here's a link to the JS Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Firefeature/rdxcagy6/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the event listener is added only once, to the elements that get rendered at first.

If you want to trigger it on every element with that id, try

```
$('body').on('click', '#sendButton', function () {})
```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdxcagy6/4/).

Comment: Tomasz, thanks, that was it.  Your suggestion works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can bind the click event to the document passing the reference
//in this case is "#sendButton"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/06j440k4/1/

Comment: Thanks, Martin, this works well too.  I will need to do some research to understand if there are any downsides to doing it this way vs. the way that Tomasz posted.  I appreciate your quick answer!